# Simple button on second view controller crashing app/ Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, iboutlet

I have a very simple app so far. Two view controllers. I've set up a new `.swift` file for the second view. On each view I have a button that when pressed, changes a label to say "Pressed". Pretty simple.

On the first view controller everything works as expected. However, on the second view controller the app crashes when I press the button. I've set up `IBOutlets` and actions for all appropriate parts.

Does anyone have any insight?

**code:**

```
import UIKit

class PlayViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var newCardButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var labelTest: UILabel!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func newCardButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    self.labelTest.text = "Pressed"
}

}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Screenshot after crash- https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1ZCd.png

Comment: Post your code, and crash logs.

Comment: and the crash message is ?

Comment: Thanks for help! The simulator shuts off and I see this message in the bottom right corner- libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) . Here is a screen shot- http://i.imgur.com/CHt8kA5.png

Comment: What does the entire crash log say? "libc++abi.dylib: terminated with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)" could mean all sorts of things. Basically, that just means an exception occurred that was not caught. Also, could you show me your connection to labelTest (ctrl-click on the label and take a photo)?

Comment: The entire thing is too long to post but I think this might be the more helpful part- 2015-07-21 21:16:16.580 Math Flash Cards[10359:616836] -[Math_Flash_Cards.PlayViewController NewCardButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd671c4b280
2015-07-21 21:16:16.585 Math Flash Cards[10359:616836] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Math_Flash_Cards.PlayViewController NewCardButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd671c4b280'

Comment: Ah! This means that the function the button sent could not be found within the class. Can you show me a photo of your connections?

Comment: Thank you so much! I got rid of all of its connections and re did them and changed the sender to "AnyObject" as suggested below and it works! Something so simple as not double checking the connections really messed me up. I really appreciate you taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change the sender part like this.

```
    @IBAction func newCardButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.labelText.text = "Pressed"
}
```

If your connections are not set properly your app also crash. Delete them and reconnect it.From Utilities/connections inspector.

Comment: I redid the connections and changed the sender as you suggested and it worked. Thanks a ton!